What happened to Immortan Joe's son, Corpus Colossus, in the "Furiosa" prequel?
In Mad Max: Fury Road (2015), we are introduced to Corpus Colossus, Immortan Joe's oldest son, and second-in-command.

I just watched Fury Road's prequel, Furiosa: A Mad Max Saga (2024), and I couldn't help but notice that Corpus Colossus is nowhere to be seen. I understand that, out-of-universe, this is out of respect for Quentin Kenihan, the actor who played him and sadly passed away in 2018. What struck me as odd, though, is that I don't recall anyone even mentioning Corpus Colossus in the movie.
Does anyone know what's supposed to be happening with Corpus Colossus during the events of Furiosa? Is there any info out there about his whereabouts or status in the prequel's timeline? I'm curious to know if I missed something or if there's any behind-the-scenes explanation.

His character's actor is mentioned in the 'farewell' portion of the credits, along with other notable cast and crew who've passed away
